# How can I pad an argument with zeroes using the lisp format function?

Tags: common-lisp

I am playing around with lisp's format function, but I have hit a snag because although I can get it to write the list of numbers aligned nicely, I can't seem to get it to zero pad it:

```
(defun inc (a) (+ 1 a))
(dotimes (i 10)
  (format t "~3@:D ~:*~R~%" (inc i)))
```

This produces the following output:

```
+1: one
+2: two
+3: three
+4: four
+5: five
+6: six
+7: seven
+8: eight
+9: nine
+10: ten
```

Does anybody know how to get it to be zero-padded?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Example lifted from [the PCL chapter on FORMAT](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html):

```
(format nil "~12d" 1000000)    ==> "     1000000"
(format nil "~12,'0d" 1000000) ==> "000001000000"
```